# Flyway db migration folder

Tags: flyway

I have a question about flyway migration folder . Does sql's have to reside in project folder Application/foo/bar/main/resources/db/migration. Could it reside outside of the application cource folder?

We are using Maven.

Answer (score 29):

By default Flyway will look for migrations on the classpath under db/migration, which on a Maven project means src/main/resources/db/migration.

You can however also use a location starting with the filesystem: prefix that can be anywhere on your disk.

[image]

See the ”Location and discovery“ section of the [*SQL-based migrations* documentation page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#sql-based-migrations).

For command-line use, see the `locations` option [on the `migrate` command reference page](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/migrate-184127460.html).

Comment: The link to the documentation page is doing a redirection.

Comment: This does not work anymore. You need the path from the repository-root. Which means try ```locations: filesystem:my-other-folder```. If you are using Intellij, just copy the path from repository root and it will work straight away. Tested this on flyway 6.4.4 and spring-boot 2.2.6.RELEASE with java version 11