# Flyway relative path in gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have gradle spring-boot project.

I was trying to set the Flyway db migration files to different location using relative path.

```
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    username: sa
    password: 
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    locations: filesystem:.\..\ITest\resources\db.migration
```

Still file cannot be found. However when I specify the absolute location. it works.

Absolute path : `C:\Projects\myApi\src\ITest\resources\db.migration`

As I understood default location would be `myApi/main/resources` in the project

Answer (score 0):

Flyway will look for scripts under the path `db/migration` folder by default.

The naming convention for all the migration scripts is `V[VERSION_NUMBER__[NAME].sql`, for example `V1_create_emp_table.sql`

You have to create migration files under `db/migration` and file name starting with `V`, here is nice [article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/database-migration-in-spring-boot-using-flyway-ee791db8aea0) with more information.

Comment: As mentioned in the question can set any other path with same folder e.g. 'db/migration' with absolute path. My requirement is to set relative path

Comment: Tried this solution as well, No luck though, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828352

Comment: Actually relative path works wih `locations: classpath:db/migration` as per this solution(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652470) dot (`.`) in the path doesn't work.